# How to use AbsoluteLayout inside the ScrollView Programmatically?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, absolutelayout

I want to display the labels with `AbsoluteLayout` view by providing x,y coordinates *programmatically*.
The issue is `ScrollView` is overriding the `AbsoluteLayout` and unable to *scroll* the page.

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` has been deprecated for about five years. Please do something else, such as creating your own custom `View` or `ViewGroup` that incorporates your own layout rules.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use AbsoluteLayout (it has been deprecated, and isn't supported).

Try to use a RelativeLayout, which generally allows a lot of control about placing your UI elements on the screen.

You can use XML or Java code to establish this layout (same as any other layout).

Keep in mind, you can generally only have 1 scrollable container inside another scrollable container, if you have more than one this could cause problems.